# Using Selenium with load Profile from Chrome Account

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

first question here so hope format is correct.

I am trying to use Selenium in order to automate a Log-In process but am encountering the following problem:

[Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VdKi.png)

As you can see I have two different versions of the driver initialiser, this is because:

- When I pick the executable to be the default chrome executable it opens a new window, with the correct profile information, but doesn't "act". It doesn't even show the usual "Chrome is being used by automated software" message
- When I pick the chromedriver executable which I downloaded to use with Selenium it opens a window without any kind of information relative to the profile loaded but goes through the entire process I asked it to

I'd be grateful for any kind of help,

Thank you in advance